How to keep data after page reload and remove on next tab or browser close
I need to keep data on page reload, but it should kill data on Browser Close. On next tab, also the same URL should not show data. That means I need data on the same tab only after page a reload.
I tried using persist, but it keeps data after Browser close also.

If you want to keep the data when reloading the page and the data is deleted on another or after closing the first, there is the solution of client-side session storage.
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('yourData')) {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('yourData');
    } else {
    var data = 'some data';
    sessionStorage.setItem('yourData', data);
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('yourData');
    });

With this you will be able to keep the data on a single page even if it is reloaded. The other pages will not have any data from this one.
